# How to create a property using groovy script?

Tags: groovy, soapui

In automation script, I am in need to create a property and store the value dynamically, so that the value stored is used in upcoming steps for further process,Could anyone help in this.

I tried online every article says on set and get property in groovy,but i need to create a property using Groovy Script test step.

Comment: Just like what Java does.

Comment: Are you using soapui?

Comment: Naveen, please check the solution and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SoapUI, the following code snippet helps to create a property at test case level.

```
//Set a test case level custom property, say COLOR
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('COLOR', 'black')

//The same can be read back using below
def color = context.expand('${#TestCase#COLOR}')
assert 'black' == color
```

I believe that the above created property should be used in other steps of the test case since property might have been create for a purpose of re-use.

Whereever color black is needed, just use `${#TestCase#COLOR}` and this notation is called as `Property Expansion`

Comment: Thanks on that Rao,Its working.I have a confusion like set is to update a existing property only,

Comment: If there is no such property, then creates property and its value. If already exists, then updates. Appreciate [if you can accept it as answered](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).